# How to use MobileDevice framework to write a file to my Application's Documents directory?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, macos

So I need to programmatically write a file to my Application's Documents directory on my iPhone. I can't use libimobiledevice for license restrictions. iphonedisk is no longer maintained and as far as I gather you can't actually access the Application data anyway.

So I think I need to use the MobileDevice framework directly.

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Why is LGPL 2.1 problematic for you?  LGPL allows for any type of program, GPL or not, to link against the covered library.  If you're using `gcc` on the Mac, you're linking against the LGPL `libc`.

Comment: Because LGPL 2.1 has clauses about being able to provide a replacement copy of whatever library. Due to the constraints of this application such a substitution would not be possible.

Comment: do you want to write a plist or a data file ? Why do you have to use MobileDevice framework and not the methods provided by iOS?

Comment: There are no methods provided by iOS.

Comment: Unless of course you are making an iPhone accessory.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using fruitstrap : https://github.com/phildrip/fruitstrap

```
fruitstrap upload [--id=device_id] --bundle-id= --file=filename [--target=filename]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this project [MobileDevice Manager](https://github.com/xslim/mobileDeviceManager). It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

So in our scenario, I needed some of my applications to share data/files. So we used a ftp server to sync data between them. I know this is a twisted way, but that was the only way to do it. There is no way to list files in a ftp folder, so we created a text file with list zip files to download. So instead of files we downloaded zip files, unzipped them and used them.